# Drastic performance difference across C++ compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2013, stl, qt-creator

Whenever I use standard library containers `stack`, `queue`, `deque` or `priority_queue`, performance in *Visual Studio* becomes inexplicably slow. The same program that can run in *gcc compiler (Qt Creator)* within few seconds takes over a minute in Visual Studio.

Here is a simple program that uses BFS to check if a number can be transformed into a target number. Allowed transformations are `x->x+1` and `x->x/2`.

Code:

```
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

const int M=10000000;
int vis[M+1];

bool can(int s, int t) {
    memset(vis, 0, sizeof(vis));
    stack<int> q;
    q.push(s);
    int m=0;
    vis[s]=true;
    while(!q.empty()) {
        m=max(m, (int)q.size());
        int top=q.top();
        q.pop();
        if(top==t) return true;
        if(top+1<=M && !vis[top+1]) {
            q.push(top+1);
            vis[top+1]=true;
        }
        if(!vis[top/2]) {
            q.push(top/2);
            vis[top/2]=true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    vector <int> S {8769154, 9843630, 2222222, 1, 3456789};
    vector<int> T {94383481, 1010101, 9999999, 9876543, 1};

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1=high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(int i=0; i<S.size(); i++) {
        cout<<can(S[i], T[i])<<endl;
    }

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2=high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    cout<<"Execution time "<<duration/1000000.0<<" second";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Visual Studio : Execution time 77.3784 second
>   Qt Creator    : Execution time 4.79727 second

Output of The same program on using stack instead of queue:

> Visual Studio : Execution time 114.896 second
>   Qt Creator    : Execution time 4.35225 second

So Qt Creator runs almost 20-30 times faster than Visual Studio in this case. I have no idea why this happens. The performance difference is very little when I Don't use these STL containers.

Comment: Which flags to you pass to each compiler ?

Comment: Not all standard library implementations are born equal.

Comment: In some configuration, visual add extra check.

Comment: what did the profiler say on the issue?

Comment: Are you using the free "express" edition of VS?  I haven't tried that for a few years, but when I did, it seemed to have some pretty nasty (and obviously intentional) anti-optimizations in its code generation.  So it was suitable for some student use, but useless for most serious use.

Comment: sorry its actually Visual Studio 2013 and yes its express edition

Comment: @Jarod42 Where do you see anything in that code for which move semantics would make a measurable performance difference?

Comment: Please show the compilation flags used with both compilers. Are you perchance comparing an optimised gcc build with a Debug VS build?

Comment: With my copy of MSVC 2013 Ultimate, your program prints `Execution time 0.48 second` in Release build, `Execution time 62.7432 second` in Debug. I suspect your are measuring performance of a debug build, which is, shall we say, unwise.

Comment: I've noticed the performance of the the MSVC2013 priority queue in debug mode is quadratic with relation to the size of the queue in some use cases. If you *need* to work in debug mode, keeping a sorted vector around instead is vastly faster in debug mode, and only slightly slower than the priority queue when in release mode. I suspect the execution time cost in debug mode is due to extra checks, myself.

Comment: I have been using Debug VS build with Optimization Disabled (/Od). So maybe that's why. In release build with Full Optimization (/Ox) it finished in around 1 second. (I cannot figure out how to print all compilation flags in VS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Visual Studio is slow in debug mode. It's partially because optimizations are off, partially because the Standard Library implementation in VC++ has a lot of checks on iterator abuse.